# CertificateException with async-http-client for https

Tags: java, ssl, asynchttpclient

I started having problems accessing a https://ws.plimus.com/ with [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) a few days ago. I get a "General SSLEngine problem" messages, and in the stack trace I can see it is caused by

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14149545) describes basically the same thing. [Commenting out the line in java.security](http://www.richardnichols.net/2012/08/arrrggh-java-security-cert-certificateexception-certificates-does-not-conform-to-algorithm-constraints/) makes the error go away, but I assume there is good reason for MD2 to be disabled.

Using [Raman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931663/7581) for hints, I found that indeed, the async-http-client library [uses the X509TrustManager interface](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/util/SslUtils.java#L110), but there's not much I can do to change that.

Running this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ws.plimus.com:443 | grep -i md2
```

finds nothing, so I don't even know which certificate is causing the issue.

Is there something I can do, other than the workaround?

I put demo code that reproduces the problem [on github](https://github.com/itsadok/async-http-client-ssl-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server you mentioned does indeed use the same Verisign Class 3 cert with the md2WithRSAEncryption algorithm that I described in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931663/7581):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -no_ign_eof -connect ws.plimus.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
... [ stripped ] ...
 3 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and then converting that certificate to text form:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout < cert.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            70:ba:e4:1d:10:d9:29:34:b6:38:ca:7b:03:cc:ba:bf
    Signature Algorithm: md2WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 29 00:00:00 1996 GMT
            Not After : Aug  1 23:59:59 2028 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
... [ stripped ] ...
```

Perusing the javadocs for async-http-client, it looks like you can call `setSSLContext` when building an instance of `AsyncHttpClientConfig`:

https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/AsyncHttpClientConfig.java#L841

So, you can create your own `SSLContext` with the `X509ExtendedTrustManager` and configure the async http client library to use it, instead of its internal default. That should solve your problem!

Here is a Gist which contains the SSL test code I used to debug this issue. You can easily extract from this what you need to create your own `SSLContext`: https://gist.github.com/rocketraman/8312705.