# SSL cert works in SOAPUI but not in Jmeter2.13

Tags: ssl, jmeter, soapui, keystore

I am testing client-server over secured connection.

I loaded keystore cert into SOAPUI and was able to connect to my server's component. However, when I configure the same keystore cert in JMeter v2.13, I am getting this error:

> Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
>   Response message: Non HTTP response message: >java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to >algorithm constraints

I've referred to many suggestion found and have
configured the path to my keystore and password in Jmeter's system.properties and added the 'Keystore Configuration'

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for answer I found that the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149545/java-security-cert-certificateexception-certificates-does-not-conform-to-algori/35157419#35157419). Potentially there's few installation in my local machine.

My issue was because I have java.security at the following directories:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\security
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\security

So, I've editted the value in java.security of C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\security and I was able to send SOAP over https.

Having solved the problem, I do hope someone is able to explain to me why my client looks for settings in JRE but not JDK.