# SSL handshake failed remote host closed connection during handshake in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to create a repository in Eclipse. The code that I need is hosted in a VisualSVN server. I am trying to use its trunk URL as the repository location, but when I try to connect to the URL through Eclipse's SVN plug-in, it fails with error SSL handshake failed.

I am using a proxy server.

I have seen solutions mentioning modifying the settings like so:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Source: [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake during web service communicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157419/2834978).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. I had to open my network connection settings in Eclipse and change the 'Active Provider' to manual instead of native. I had to do this because my visual svn server was not allowing me to connect to it through a proxy server, and native was using the proxy.

(also, I checked this at the get-go but it was not showing my proxy server for some reason in eclipse's network connection dialog box)

Comment: For anyone else reading this, remember to restart Eclipse if the changes don't take effect immediately. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/connecting-jazz-repository-results-failed-contact-repository-error

Answer (score 0):

1. Update SVN plug-in that you use in Eclipse. It seems that it is very outdated.
2. Try setting the [TLS/SSL compatibility level](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00105/) to **Legacy** in VisualSVN Server's settings.