QuickFIX/J - Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
I am currently developing a QuickFIX/J application running on Java 17, intended to establish a secure connection with an external party using provided JKS certificates. Upon attempting the connection, I am encountering a java.security.cert.CertificateException with the message Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints.
Here are the details:

QuickFIX/J version: 2.3.1
Java version: 17
Error Message: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints

I have attached the relevant portions of my QuickFIX/J configuration and the stack trace of the error. Could anyone provide advice on how to resolve this certificate issue or suggest any configurations that might prevent this error?
Thank you very much for any help you can provide!
My QuickFIX/J configuration
ConnectionType=initiator
SocketConnectHost=my_ip
SocketConnectPort=my_port
SocketUseSSL=Y
CipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
SocketKeyStore=/path/cert.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=my_passowrd
SocketTrustStore=/path-trust/truststore.jks
SocketTrustStorePassword=my_password

My error
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|A2|NioProcessor-2|2024-05-08 16:28:46.528 BRT|TransportContext.java:370|Fatal (UNSUPPORTED_CERTIFICATE): Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints (
"throwable" : {
  java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1573)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1538)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.doTasks(SslHandler.java:816)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:591)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.messageReceived(SslHandler.java:356)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:517)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:643)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:539)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1224)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1213)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:237)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1569)
    ... 30 more}

Requirements from the party to the connection


Listing the cipher suites textually:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

In this post QuickFIX/J CipherSuites , I received a tip on what CipherSuites I need to inform.

Did you check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/14149545/4962355 ? Especially check if algorithms are disabled for your JDK and use the openssl command to check which certificate chain the other side expects.

@ChristophJohn+ or javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake or keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port] both of which decode the certs for you (vs an additional step with openssl). And you need (and get) the chain the other side sends not expects.

Thanks for the help @ChristophJohn and @dave_thompson_085
Clarifying my problem
I was tasked with establishing a connection with an acceptor using a JKS certificate. Upon inspecting the certificate using the command keytool -list -v -keystore cert.jks -storepass my_password, I discovered that it employs the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm.
According to the error stack trace, this algorithm is not accepted by my current Java security policy. Ideally, the solution would involve obtaining a new certificate that doesn't use SHA1withRSA. However, due to constraints beyond my control, this was not feasible. Consequently, I was compelled to find a way to adjust my Java security properties to permit the use of this algorithm.
Solution
Following the advices from these two posts java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints and Java Algorithm constraints check failed on key RSA with size of 1024bits , I changed my java.security to allow SHA1withRSA.
