# How to post data to https website on GAE(Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, post, https

On Google App Engine,I am using JAVA.
I have some question about my project.

I want to get some data from a website which needs to login

Usually, I will use HttpURLConnection below to accomplish this job

The question is, the website is not "http://..." but "https://.."
above code does not work.

how can I login to the website using java on GAE?

Comment: `HttpsUrlConnection` is the corresponding class for HTTPS

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022717/java-and-https-url-connection-without-downloading-certificate for the URL connection. Check the conversation you will find Code and answer which you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use SSL certificates, and to be honest I have yet to use keystores and such on GAE.

Can you post your stacktrace please ?