# SSL certificate issue javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Tags: java

I am trying to open one htttps website. Url is for ex. https://x.xx.xx.xx/. I have written the blow code.

String url = "https://x.xx.xx.xx/";

URL obj = new URL(url);

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// optional default is GET 
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//add request header 
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

But its throwing the exception "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative" . I am new to Java.
Can anyone help me how to resolve the above issue.

have imported certificate sucessfuly, still getting the exception, can anyone please help me?

Have impor

Comment: Check this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: Hi Nirmal, Do I need to ask for certificate from Sever admin or I should create it?

Comment: You can download it from the browser by visiting that site. This post will be helpful. http://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file

Comment: I Have cacerts that comes default with jdk. How shall I import in my java trust store?

Comment: Have downloaded and imported certificate sucessfully, still getting the above exception. A quick reply would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two solution :
 import the server certificate to your java trust store or create a custom unsecured TrustManager trusting all certificats see [Java and HTTPS url connection without downloading certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022717/java-and-https-url-connection-without-downloading-certificate) for an exemple.

Comment: I Have cacerts that comes default with jdk. How shall I import in my java trust store?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate option 1 explain what to do to import a cert in trust store.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried 2nd option and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Nemesis, I by passed the certificate using 2nd option given above but still got ssl certificate error can you tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: Please post complete stack trace so we can help you (if pb still occurs) and a more complete set of code if possible.