# Connecting via SSL with Java: The basics

Tags: java, ssl

I need to connect to a URL over HTTPS using Java. I don't have any experience with SSL certificates, and most of the questions here assume some basic knowledge. I was hoping someone here could get me started on the basics.

When I put the URL in my browser, it connects just fine. When I do it using Java:

```
new URL("https://mysite.com/").openStream()
```

it throws `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022717) shows how to ignore the whole certificate thing, but that doesn't feel right. I simply want to use the same certificate my browser does.

I've already tried adding the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts` property, which changes the exception to `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`, which I've taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463) to mean it can't find the trust store called `cacerts`. I'm not sure what else to specify, though.

Comment: It seems that `mysite.com` uses self-signed certificate, or so. Have you imported the certificate that `mysite.com` offers to `cacerts`?

Comment: I haven't added anything manually. I figure since my browser can find the certificate, Java should be able somehow too, I just have to tell it where to look.

Comment: you need to use the `keytool` command that comes with the jvm to import the server certificate (and most probably the root CA that signed it) in your keystore. `cacerts` is the default CAs store shipped with the jvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites use self-signed certificates for ssl. You should add them to your JRE's `cacerts` file. In such cases I use following steps:

1. Go to `https://mysite.com` with your browser
2. Save its certificate to your local machine
3. Import it to your cacerts with keytool command. The command line looks like this: `keytool -import -alias mysite -file mysite.cer -keystore {path/to/cacerts}`

As an alternative, you can use `openssl s_client` utility to retreive `mysite.com` certificate.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! I created a new keystore instead of using cacerts, since I'm not sure what password it wanted, but that's a minor detail. So, if I understand correctly, my browser automatically detects the site has a so called `self-signed certificate` and imports it automatically, but I have to find and import it manually in order for Java to recognize that.

Comment: Default password for JRE's cacerts is `changeit`

Comment: Yes, browsers can detect that certificate is self-signed, or so. Usually, they show a warning like this: `The site's security certificate is not trusted` in such cases.