# SSL Error handler

Tags: android, ssl

Hi im trying to upload my game to the google play store and it is getting rejected because of it being vulnerable due to SSL Error Handler here is the full message

Hello Google Play Developer,

We rejected SquareSwipe, with package name com.JBGames.Square_Swipe, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability   APK Version(s)
SSL Error Handler
For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

1
To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.

While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.

Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out to our developer support team.

Best,

The Google Play Team.

They link a way to solve this problem but I really dont understand what is going on here.If you could help that would be great

Comment: see this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/35618839/4146722

Comment: Im not quite sure how to implement this? do I just put the code mentioned in this thread into a script and then reupload the apk or is there other steps required?

Comment: does your url have Https ?

Comment: Where do I go to check my URL?

Comment: see this "This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure" it means you have not prompting dialog or notify user that app going to use data or opening web. to solve that you have to show dialog and allow user to interact with that see my answer and question on that page

Comment: you have to give WebView SSL Error Handler alert.

Comment: OK How would I do that?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35618839/4146722