# How can I solution to SSL Error Handler - React-Native-Webview

Tags: react-native, android-security, react-native-webview

My application with a version of react-native 0.60.4, uses the reat-native-webview library, the version of reat-native-webview has been updated from 9.4.0 to 10.6.0, when updating that version when wanting to update it in the playstore it did not allow attached the image of the error

[SSL Error Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSORO.png)

I went back to the version before 9.4.0, because I had read in many forums that it is better to remove that part, (I attach the links https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE/commit/85dadbfd7b31346b11ce642d4224e12561c8b169 https: // stackoverflow .com / questions / 35720753 / android-google-play-warning-ssl-error-handler-vulnerability / 35721678 # 35721678 [How can load https url without use of ssl in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569047/how-can-load-https-url-without-) use-of-ssl-in-android-webview / 35618839 # 35618839 -> in the comments mention that this solution did not work [Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-) play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds / 36147896 # 36147896)

that's why it was that I go back to version 9.4.0 and it keeps showing me the same error, it is assumed that version 10.6.0 has already added the solution to this error, however the playstore keeps rejecting it

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/commit/1bd596125599af1cbba6964876e305bb42a4e4cf?branch=1bd596125599af1cbba6964876e305bb42a4e4cf&diff=split

I have checked all the urls of the application and they are all correct with https

Has anyone managed to resolve this error?

Comment: Check out the latest answer (by me ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-an-https-url/63645866#63645866 I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was react-native-sodyo library, it was not in react-native-webview, the library of sodyo in his last update have this issue. So I did use the same with that

[Android WebView not loading an HTTPS URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-an-https-url/63645866#63645866)