# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, using HttpURLConnection on page GET

Tags: java, networking, https, httpurlconnection, socketexception

Programmatically getting page with Java (HttpURLConnection) gives me error java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Works with Python and with Postman.

Tried with other pages like gmail login page, ebanking login page etc. and it works, but only for one site (the one I need it to work) doesn't. Succeded with  Python script, Postman also works, but Java doesn't

```
String url="https://********************/Login";
URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Expected to not throw exception.
Actual result is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
...
```

Python script which works:

```
import urllib.request  as urllib2 
content = urllib2.urlopen('https://******************/Login').read()
print(content)
```

Comment: The server does not like the HttpClient for some reason.  Maybe it thinks something is malformed or incorrect SSL cipher suites.  Connection reset just means that the connection was terminated by the other party abnormally.  You should do a pcap and look at the server logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to HttpsURLConnection:

```
String url = "https://********************/Login";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

Code in sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)

[image]

maybe a proxy is reason of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it didn't solve a problem.

Comment: If you need a https connection without verification any certificate you will be able to use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022717/java-and-https-url-connection-without-downloading-certificate Otherwise you have to download a cert and add it to your connection.

Comment: Thanks, I've used the code with other sites with HTTPS connection , and it worked, without explicitly importing their certificate.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, i tried to remove proxy with obj.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY); and its the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hello, do you get a same stack trace of this error?

Comment: Yeap, its the same.